# Package & Variable Gain Amplifier Identification

Tags: amplifier, rf, identification, vga

I am trying to identify an unknown wideband VGA whose markings were scratched off. It is apparently a 5W amplifier, drawing 1A @ 5V power supply, with analog gain control - using a 10k potentiometer.

Operating frequency is a mystery as well, I can only assume that it's between 0.4 - 3.0 GHz based on other used components.

The package is aprox. 10x10mm in size and looks like an LGA, but I couldn't find anything like it in KiCAD to help me with the search.

Does anyone know what package this might be?

[image: VGA Back]

[image: VGA Front]

Comment: What's on the other side of the part? Any markings etc?

Comment: All markings were removed - as you can see in the updated post. I'm assuming that the amplifier is cheap, for the category of Wideband Power Amplifiers, and that's why I'm interested. Found something similar from Qorvo, but the power output is not even close to 5W.